# Can not use wifi without connecting to VPN on Manjaro

Tags: networking, vpn, manjaro

I'm relatively new to linux. I was using Outline VPN on Manjaro for a while. Recently, wifi stopped working when I'm not connected to the VPN. I could only use wifi when I'm connected to VPN even though the wifi connection displays as "connected". This happens every time I boot my pc. I can temporarily fix it by connecting and disconnecting to the VPN. But the wifi breaks again every time I boot. How can I fix this so I can use wifi without connecting to vpn.

```
> ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.125 metric 3002 
10.0.85.0/24 dev outline-tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.85.1 linkdown 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.124 metric 600 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.125 metric 3002
```

```
> sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

```
> cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 216.146.35.35
options use-vc
nameserver 216.146.35.35
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8
options use-vc
```

Any help would be nice.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you check DNS? can you ping "well known" IP addresses like 8.8.8.8?

Comment: @A.B Yup. I can ping DNS address no problem even when VPN turned off.

Comment: Part of what VPN clients do is modify your routing and firewall rules. If those rules are still in place, it makes sense that nothing works after the VPN connection breaks. Have a look at (and please show) output from commands such as `ip route` and `iptables -S` (or whatever firewall you're using).

Comment: @cryptarch I added the outputs to the question

Comment: @Matt Ah I overlooked the comment where you said you can ping IP addresses even with the VPN turned off. So the problem is name resolution, not connection. Can you please show the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: @cryptarch Ok. Also added the resolv.conf contents.

Comment: @Matt I'm not familiar with that address 216.146.35.35. Is that associated with your VPN? What happens if you change the resolv.conf to simply have one line saying `nameserver 8.8.8.8`? (Perhaps back up the original resolv.conf first.)

Comment: @cryptarch Yeah that address comes from the VPN. Changing the resolv.conf works great until I reboot my computer and it changes back to the original. Is there a way to make the changes permanent or would that break stuff?

Comment: @Matt Making permanent changes to resolv.conf is at least partly distro-dependent. A common method is to place files under `/etc/resolv.conf.d/`, but this isn't universal. These days, many distros might also go for a solution provided by systemd (but I never touch the stuff myself, so I'm not sure). Personally I use dnscrypt-proxy + dnsmasq, eg have a look through https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dnscrypt-proxy (especially the dnsmasq section).

Comment: If you were using the openvpn client, it would be possible to script changes to resolv.conf so that a backup is created upon launching the client, and restored after shutting the vpn off. I do this for ExpressVPN. But I'm under the impression you're using the official app from your vpn provider?

Comment: @cryptarch Yeah I was using the official app. I did a "lazy" solution by making `resolv.conf` immutable. It works for now. But I'll try to setup openvpn to see if that works.